# Why is the stroke order of も peculiar?

Tags: stroke-order, irregularities-exceptions

In most hiragana the horizonal stokes are drawn first, but も is an exception. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: http://www.jref.com/forum/learning-japanese-64/stroke-order-%82%E0-doesnt-follow-rules-46305/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think silvermaple's answer is right, but to add a little bit:

- The katakana `モ` was derived from the 楷書体 (block writing)　[`毛`](http://www.winttk.com/kakijun/2/20230.htm). **The initial short stroke was dropped**, ending up with two horizontal strokes, and then the vertical stroke.
- The hiragana `も` was derived from the 草書体 (script) `毛`, in which, for the sake of writing speed, **the vertical stroke was conflated with and became part of the initial short stroke**, ending up with the initial long stroke and then the two horizontal strokes.

Answer (score 4):

To quote [Toritoribe](https://www.jref.com/forum/threads/stroke-order-of-%E3%82%82-doesnt-follow-the-rules.46305/) from JapaneseReference (JRef.com) forums:

> も was made from the 草書体[そうしょたい] of the kanji 毛[モウ, け]. So, the stroke
>   order of も was also from the the stroke order of 毛. Incidentally, the
>   stroke order is different in 楷書体[かいしょたい]. (The link of the wiktionary
>   page doesn't work due to garbled characters. Please search 毛 on
>   Wiktionary. The page has the flash of the stroke order.)

And then, on why `も` and `モ` have different stroke orders, and the origins of `ね`, `わ`, and `れ`:

> モ was made from 毛 in 楷書体 unlike も. That's why those two kanas have
>   different stroke orders.
>
> ね, わ, れ are from the 草書体 of 祢, 和, 礼 respectively

Comment: Does this say that the cursive of 毛 is も?

Comment: the 草書体. Kinda confused about whether 毛 and も are the same in 草書体.

Comment: @Louis Oh! Duh! I think it's saying that's the other way around...